# How do you open a page over your current tab?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

**Reason**

I previously asked the same question but using a different language (small basic), yet received little help. For this reason, I re-scripted the program in python hoping to reach a wider audience, despite the fact I am a beginner with python.

**What am I trying to do?**

I'm trying to create a program that generates a random URL subdirectory for an open image database and then opens the URL in the default browser.

**What's wrong?**

Despite the fact I instruct the code to open over the current tab using

> `new=0, autoraise=True`

No matter what I do it opens a new instance of the page, which is pointless as the base URL remains the same and only the directories change.

**My code**

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
import random
import string

root = Tk()
root.title("Image Browser")
root.geometry("300x70")

def google():
    rannums = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for n in range(4))
    ranstring = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(2))
    urlsuffix = ranstring + rannums
    url = "https://prnt.sc/" + urlsuffix
    webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
    root.focus_force()
 

mygoogle = Button(root, text="Random Image", command=google).pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```